# Sending Email to address that is saved inside csv file in Talend

Tags: email, talend

I need to send an email at the end of ETL tool. However I need the email address to be extracted from the tfileinputdelimited.

Right now I have twaitforfile -> tflowtoiterate -> tfileinputdelimited -> tmap_1 -> tbdoutput ->tsendemail What I want to do is get the email from the tfileinputdelimited, I dont know the email ahead of time thats why I can't add a predefined list. It all depends on the new file added and detected by the file watcher. I can't also add global variable to tfileinputdelimited since the tfileinputdelimited is connected to other things from both sides shown above

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an image of your interface?

Comment: Hello, I added the picture in the question. Actually just little change in the question. I want to capture the email address from one of the files in the folder through the file watcher, and then add the files I have into another sub directory. So for example if I have 5 files inside the directory and one of them has the email address, I want to take that email address, store in database and also store it for later also to be used in email component. Then move all the 5 files into another subdirectory, in which they will be processed , (each mapped to the database" )

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that tSendMail is initialized before the 1st line. Hence it gets null values.

The solution is simple: tFlowToIterate before that component then you will have your values that can be used. This error happens a lot if you don't know how Talend components are build up.